# Access subtype of type hint

Tags: python, type-hinting

```
class MyClass:
    prop: list[str]

MyClass.__annotations__
# {'prop': list[str]}
```

How do I access "str"?

As a more generic question, given an obnoxiously complex and long type hint, like `prop: list[set[list[list[str] | set[int]]]]`, how do I access the internal values programmatically?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args

Comment: Given that Python typing hints have zero impact at runtime, I think you’ll need to clarify what you mean by “access” and what for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that will recursively pretty print the type and all the types inside it, using `typing.get_args` as suggested by @user2357112 :

```
from typing import List, Set, Union
import typing

complex_type = Union[List[str], Set[int]]

def log_type_layers(typing_type, indent=4, depth=0):
    current_type = typing_type
    print(" "*indent*depth + str(current_type))
    for subtype in typing.get_args(current_type):
        log_type_layers(subtype, indent=indent, depth=depth+1)
        
log_type_layers(complex_type)
```

Output:

```
typing.Union[typing.List[str], typing.Set[int]]
    typing.List[str]
        <class 'str'>
    typing.Set[int]
        <class 'int'>
```